# Search results ordering based on rating and other values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, rails-postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am struggling to build a complex ordering algorithm for the search results page.

I would like to order my items by rating (rating count, average rating), but I only want the rating take between 60-80% of the results page. One page has 12 items. They should be distributed randomly on a page.

I want to apply simple ordering as a secondary criteria, such as `created_at` field.

Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

Comment: *I only want the rating take between 60-80% of the results page. One page has 12 items.* ... so you want f.ex. the first page to include the top 10 rated items and the 2 most fresh, the second to include the second most rated 10 and the second 2 most fresh item, etc. (obviously without duplicates)? Or you just want `ORDER BY rating DESC, created_at ASC`? (but that seems rather obvious to make a question for it).

Comment: The first indeed. Around 8 results with rating and 4 results fresh. Preferably mixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a solution which includes a chance of not rated items to end up in the middle of rated items. The idea of the algorithm is as follows:

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN rating IS NOT NULL OR RANDOM() < 0.0x THEN 1 + RANDOM()ELSE RANDOM() END 
DESC NULLS LAST
```

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of your requirements are:

- 12 total items returned
- 4 items should be the most recently created items
- The remaining 8 should be the highest rated items
- Items should not appear twice, so if an item is recently created AND highly rated, we will need an extra item

In order to achieve this, I tried the following:

1. Assign ordered row numbers to both the created_at and avg_rating columns
2. Calculate the number of items that are in BOTH the top 4 for created and top 8 for items (we'll call this num_duplicates)
3. Increase the total number of highly rated items to be returned by num_duplicates

[SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c67b9/9)

```
    select *
    from 
    (
      select a.*,
             sum( 
                /* We want the total number of items that meet both criteria */
                /* For every one of these items, we want to include an extra row */
                case when created_row_num <= 4 and rating_row_num <= 8 
                 then 1 
                 else 0 
               end ) over() as num_duplicates
      from (
        select  ratings.*,
                row_number() over( order by created_at desc ) as created_row_num,
                row_number() over( order by avg_rating desc ) as rating_row_num
        from    ratings
      ) as a
    ) as b
    where   created_row_num <= 4
            /* Get top 8 by rating, plus 1 for every record that has already been selected by creation date */
            or rating_row_num <= 8 + num_duplicates
```

Comment: Sorry, that I did not respond earlier to your advice. I needed some time to understand your solution. When I finally implemented it, I realized that the solution was too complex and that the query took too long. See the solution I ended up using in the end in my answer.